# Am I able to upgrade to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, laptop

I have a HP Pavilion dv5224ea (60gb hard drive, 512mb memory and 1.6Ghz Intel Core Duo Processor) laptop which was classed as “Vista Capable”. I have since upgraded the hard drive to a 250gb drive and upgraded the memory to 4gb. Will I be able to run Windows 7 on it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to. Core Duos don't support x64, so you'll need the x86 version, but the specs are fine. I have it running on a C2D 1.6 with 2GB RAM and its flawless. The processor in my machine is a little newer than yours, but the Core Duo will handle it no problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to.  I run it on my laptop, which is a 2ghz dual core pentium (based on the core 2 mobile) and it runs well.  The MS hardware requirments are [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/systemrequirements)

Answer (score 1):

As many have said - if you can run Vista you can probably run Windows 7.  If you'd like something official, try the Microsoft Windows Upgrade Advisor.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/upgrade-advisor.aspx

It'll also tell you programs that are known to have issues and suggest possible workarounds, if available. For example, it will tell you to deauthorize your computer in iTunes (if you have iTunes installed).