# Where can I get the Audio Driver for a HP Pavillion dv5224ea with Windows 7 installed?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, audio

This question once again extends my other two questions ([1](https://superuser.com/questions/59542/advice-please-upgrade-to-windows-7-even-if-laptop-vendor-does-not-supply-drivers), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/56969/able-to-upgrade-to-windws-7)).

I have installed Windows 7 and everything is working except the audio device (High Definition Audio). When I open "Manage Audio Devices" it says "No audio device found". I opened Device Manager and under "Sound, video and game controllers" it says "High Definition Audio Device" it has a little yellow exclamation mark. When I open Properties it says "This device cannot start. (Code 10)". I am using the default Microsoft Driver. I have tried re-installing the driver (using Windows Update), but it just says that I have the most up to date driver. I can't rollback the driver. There are no sound drivers from the [HP Driver Download Page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=za&lang=en&os=2093&product=3223530&). The audio hardware does work as when I run OpenSolaris Live CD the audio is fine. OpenSolaris reports the Audio Hardware as "Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) High Definition Audio Controller". I have searched the web and found a site called ["http://www.bioticaindia.com"](http://www.bioticaindia.com/82801g-ich7-family-high-definition-audio.html) which has the driver I think I need. Whenever I try to download the driver, it tells me that I need to register with them which I have tried 8 times, but the email they tell they sent does not arrive (I've tried with 3 different email addresses). I also tried the "download 1 file" link at the bottom, but still can't receive emails).

Where can I download the driver I require or is there something else I can do to get the audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to get a driver. Ended up using a old XP driver...