# Will I have to update drivers when upgrading from Windows XP to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

If i upgrade my Windows XP to Windows 7 or install Windows 7 on my current PC which is 2 years old, Will i have to update any driver for Windows 7?

Comment: Duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/56969/am-i-able-to-upgrade-to-windows-7

Comment: @ChrisF: i can't agree with designating this as a duplicate of that. i'm sure it's a duplicate of something, but that question does not address driver issues.

Comment: True, drivers can be an issue in some cases and make this question different. Though @Jitendra will have to add some information on the system or rewrite the question so that the answers will help other people solve their problems as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, many of the drivers designed for Windows XP will not work with windows seven. You can check on your hardware provider's page to see if they have suitable drivers.

Overall, the support for windows seven is pretty good.

Comment: As stated in other answers there is no upgrade path from XP to Windows 7.  Most likely different drivers will be needed on Windows 7 even though it is likely that those drivers already exist.

Answer (score 1):

There's no upgrade from Windows XP to Windows 7 so you'll need to do a clean install. You'll need Windows 7 drivers for your hardware as Windows XP drivers won't work.

Answer (score 0):

As @joeqwerty states, you cannot "upgrade" to W7 from XP - a clean install is required. The install will save the Documents and Settings, Program Files, and XP windows folder. However, the PC I installed W7 on is about as old as yours, and all of the hardware worked after a clean install without downloading any drivers. It just depends on if your hardware is supported or not. If it's common, it will likely be supported. That's not to say you wouldn't benefit from getting a new driver if available from the manufacturer.  The definitive answer is "maybe".

Answer (score 0):

90% of the time it has all the drivers or most of the drivers. In my experience, on the machines that I did a custom install on, not upgrades, I ended up having to install only graphics card drivers from either the manufacturer or the PC Manufacturer (i.e. Dell or HP), for something like Nvidia, there's general purpose drivers on their site.

So basically you're gonna need to get the drivers for the following (what 7 usually didn't or never installed for me):

Memory Card Readers (The ones in the HP Desktops)
Graphics Cards (not Intel ones)
Sound Drivers

Any miscenallenous drivers for something a bit esoteric like remotes or keyboards are usually installed quickly my windows update, only problem might be the printers because, (external devices that readily plugged in), since you've been using the machine, you're gonna assume they're installed but just plug them in after updating 7 and you'll be set.

Also before you go and search for the CD or go to the site to download, just update windows restart when it says, and do it through a couple of times since it doesn't update all the drivers at once, 99% of the time it will find the drivers it didn't automatically install via windows update.